# Как правильно писать Скупщик краденого или краденного

Tags: орфография

Скупщик краденого или краденного.

Answer (score 2):

Краденое - краденого.  Прилагательное без приставки.  Как "мороженое".

Comment: Да, всё правильно, вариант прямо из словаря: КРАДЕНЫЙ, Добытый кражей, украденный. Краденые вещи. <Краденое, ср. собир. Скупщик краденого. Образование от бесприставочного глагола несовершенного вида. Но здесь переход прилагательного в существительное.

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к ответу Виктора и комментарию Веры -

Это слово вызывает неуверенность, потому что существует причастие "краде**нн**ый", в котором как раз используются две буквы "Н". Пример:

> Краде**нн**ый со взломом товар. (причастие, имеется зависимое обстоятельство "*со взломом*")
>   Краде**н**ый товар. (прилагательное, нет зависимых слов)

---

Интересно, в Гугл Букс выкопал цитату из Успенского (1884)

> Кабы я рубилъ въ лѣсу,–ну, такъ... А то мнѣ какое дѣло? **Краденный** онъ или нѣтъ, на мнѣ отвѣту не будетъ...

И еще из дореволюционного ([Леонтович, 19 век](https://books.google.ru/books?id=g_oIAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT89&dq=%22%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%22&hl=ru&pg=PT89#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%22&f=false))

> Кто у кого опознаетъ **краденный** свой скотъ, или имѣніе и вещи, а тотъ, у кого найдено, покажетъ, что онъ купилъ, но продавца того не признаетъ...

---

Источники:

- "[Универсальный справочник русского языка](https://books.google.ru/books?id=407pAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA716&dq=%22%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%22&hl=ru&pg=PA716#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%22&f=false)"

Comment: Вы в какой-то мере правы, я тоже сомневалась при выборе Н и НН, но потом остановилась на формальном решении, те более что оно указано в словаре и пишется в реальных текстах. В качестве примера с двумя НН можно привести слова "виденное" и слышанное", которые пишутся вопреки формальному правилу, например: "Вот и я «для внутреннего своего потребления», сопоставляя виденное, слышанное и читанное, составил некий свод взглядов.."